# USB drive only reading on Disk Utility

Tags: usb, drive

I was copying music to USB and got an error.  From then on USB was reading as ‘Read Only’.  I’ve trie. Umount but USB not reading on Terminal.  It is not reading on Gparted as well.  Would like to format it, but not sure what else to do.   Tried Chowd as well.   Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can analyze the problem and try to make the drive work again. If the partition table or file system is damaged, you can repair it. But if the internal system of the USB drive (hardware or software) is damaged, there is not much to do. If the *drive* is read-only alias 'gridlocked' you cannot fix it with the tools available to normal users. There are detailed tips at this link, [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035).

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing happened to me with an sd card adapter once and it turned out there was a plastic knobble on the adapter that could be moved and it was set to read only so I had to flip it. I am not sure if USBs have this kind of write protection, but if you find a flippable knoble than try flipping it.